# data.table: get index per group || two data.table

Tags: r, data.table, match, grouping

I have two data frame in data.table forms. One has grouped data for which I would like extract index of values from the second data.table frame. Below are sample data

```
snp_bygene<-data.table(V2=c("SNP1","SNP2","SNP3","SNP4","SNP5","SNP11","SNP12","SNP13","SNP14","SNP15"),
GENE=c( rep("GENE1",5),rep("GENE2",5) ),START=c(rep(100,5),rep(200,5)),END=c(rep(190,5),rep(290,5)) )

snp_data<-data.table(V2=c("SNP1","SNP2","SNP3","SNP4","SNP5","SNP11","SNP12","SNP13","SNP14","SNP15"),BP=c(101,102,105,110,125,201,202,205,210,225))
```

I would like to get index for V2 in `snp_bygene` matched by `snp_data` V2. Per gene I would like to get SNP position.

```
setkey(snp_data, V2)
snp_bygene[snp_data]
```

How do I proceed?

Final output would be look like:
`finalindex_perGene<-list("GENE1"=c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5) , "GENE2" =c(6, 7, 8, 9, 10))`

Edit 1: there is no `GENE` group in `snp_data`

Comment: Hi - updated my question. Thank you. No there is no group in `snp_data`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could do a non-equi join `on` 'START', 'END' columns with 'BP' and equi join with 'V2', get the row index with `.I`, append the 'GENE' column in the `list` and then `split` the `.I` (`I` is the default column name created for `.I` as we didn't specify any column name - it could be made explicit by `.(I = .I, GENE)`), by 'GENE'

```
with(snp_bygene[snp_data, .(.I, GENE), on = .(V2, START <= BP, 
       END >= BP)], split(I, GENE))
```

-output

```
#$GENE1
#[1] 1 2 3 4 5

#$GENE2
#[1]  6  7  8  9 10
```

Comment: Thank you. This `with(snp_bygene[snp_data, .(.I, GENE), on = .(V2)], split(I, GENE))` also works. Can you please explain what I. I are doing? Also, I will have rows >150K.

Comment: @DeathMetal I added some description.  Hope it helps

Comment: @akrun2 - I think the `.I` returns position after the BP>= and BP<=END index. However, I am looking for index from original `snp_data` 
snp_bygene[snp_data, .(.I, GENE), on = .(V2, START <= BP, 
       END >= BP)]  

If you try with following data, you'd see what I mean: 
snp_bygene<-data.table(V2=c("SNP2","SNP1","SNP4","SNP3","SNP5","SNP11","SNP12","SNP13","SNP14","SNP15"),
GENE=c( rep("GENE1",5),rep("GENE2",5) ),START=c(rep(100,5),rep(200,5)),END=c(rep(190,5),rep(290,5)) )

Comment: @DeathMetal What would be the expected otutput here

Comment: @akrun2 
list("GENE1"=c(2,1, 4, 3, 5) , "GENE2" =c(6, 7, 8, 9, 10)) 

That is index of SNP in the original `snp_data` data.frame.  Sorry if my example is confusing.

Comment: @DeathMetal May be your example works just with `match` similar to ThomasIsCoding solution `with(snp_bygene, split(match(V2, snp_data$V2), GENE))`

Answer (score 1):

If `BP` is not involved for merging data tables (i.e., depending on `V2` only), we could use `chmatch` to obtain the matched row indices, e.g.,

```
> with(snp_bygene, split(chmatch(snp_bygene[, V2], snp_data[, V2]), GENE))
$GENE1
[1] 1 2 3 4 5

$GENE2
[1]  6  7  8  9 10
```

Otherwise, you may need non-equi and equi joins as [@akrun did](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65724859/12158757)